# How do I link gtk4 library statically with cmake on windows?

Tags: c, cmake, gtk, static-linking

How can I link gtk4 library statically with cmake on windows.

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.14.0)

set( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "D:/Programs/msys64/clang64/bin/clang++.exe" )
set( CMAKE_C_COMPILER "D:/Programs/msys64/clang64/bin/clang.exe" )
set( CMAKE_GENERATOR "Ninja" )

project(LianLianKanSolver)

set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".a")
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK REQUIRED GTK4)


file(GLOB_RECURSE GAME_SOURCE_FILES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "src/game/*.c")
file(GLOB_RECURSE GUI_SOURCE_FILES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "src/ui/*.c")

add_executable(gui
    ${GAME_SOURCE_FILES}
    ${GUI_SOURCE_FILES}
)

target_include_directories(gui PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
target_include_directories(gui PRIVATE ${GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(gui PRIVATE ${GTK_LIBRARIES})
```

`cmake .` goes well but error occurs when linking

Output:

```
[1/1] cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\Programs\msys64\clang64\bin\clang.exe  -static CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/game/board.c.obj CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/game/click.c.obj CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/game/solve.c.obj CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/game/window.c.obj CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/ui/api.c.obj CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/ui/gui.c.obj -o gui.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libgui.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lgtk-4  -lpangowin32-1.0  -lpangocairo-1.0  -lpango-1.0  -lharfbuzz  -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0  -lcairo-gobject  -lcairo  -lgraphene-1.0 
 -lgio-2.0  -lgobject-2.0  -lglib-2.0  -lintl  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 
-ladvapi32 && cd ."
FAILED: gui.exe
cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\Programs\msys64\clang64\bin\clang.exe  -static CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/game/board.c.obj CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/game/click.c.obj CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/game/solve.c.obj CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/game/window.c.obj CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/ui/api.c.obj CMakeFiles/gui.dir/src/ui/gui.c.obj -o gui.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libgui.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  -lgtk-4  -lpangowin32-1.0  -lpangocairo-1.0  -lpango-1.0  -lharfbuzz  -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0  -lcairo-gobject  -lcairo  -lgraphene-1.0  -lgio-2.0  -lgobject-2.0  -lglib-2.0  -lintl  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
lld: error: unable to find library -lgtk-4
lld: error: unable to find library -lgraphene-1.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

It says `can not find library -lgtk-4`, but I already installed gtk4 with msys2.

And everything goes well if I remove `-static` flags.

Comment: "It says `can not find library -lgtk-4`, but I already installed gtk4 with msys2." - Does your GTK4 installation contains **static** libraries? This is what you request by adding `-static` flag. If you doesn't have static libraries for GTK4, then you obviously cannot link GTK4 statically.

Comment: you need to install gtk*-dev libraries or if they are not available build the package from the source using -Ddefault_library=static

Comment: @Tsyvarev If static library are end with '.a', then yes, the installation contains static library. But they end with '.dll.a', is that the problem?